# Optimization of obvious task

Tags: arrays, c

My task is very simple, but the most obvious solution is too slow.

I have a massive of positive elements and some questions connected with this massive. I have to find the longest segment (l,r) (with given l) with the sum of the elements less than given S. My code should be in the C language, I have tried to find that (l,r) segment with trivial `for` or `while` (just starting cycle for l element and going farther while sum is less then S, but it's too slow). My teacher recommended me to count all sums from `0` to `i` and use this sums to find needed segment (l,r), but I really have no idea how to make it. Example of test:

```
10 7
1
4
0
5
6
0
0
1
5
3
0 100
0 5
4 11
4 12
4 13
10 100
```

First number `N` (`10`) is the number of elements in massive
Second number `K` (`7`) is the number of tests
Next 10 numbers (`1,4,0,5,6,0,0,1,5,3`) are elements of array
Last 7 pairs of elements are tests (first number is `l` and second is `sum`)
And the anwsers are

```
10
3
8
9
9
10
8
```

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t Query (uint32_t l, uint64_t sum,const uint32_t *arr,uint32_t n);


int main() {;
    FILE *f = fopen("input.txt","r");
    FILE *s = fopen("output.txt","w");
    uint32_t n,t,l;
    uint64_t sum;
    fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&t);
    uint32_t *arr = malloc(sizeof (uint32_t) * n);
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fscanf(f,"%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        fscanf(f,"%d %lld",&l,&sum);
        Query(l,sum,arr,n);
    }
    return 0;
}

uint32_t Query (uint32_t l, uint64_t sum,const uint32_t *arr,uint32_t n){
    uint64_t summy = 0;
    uint32_t  i;
    for( i = l ; i < n; i++){
        summy+= arr[i];
        if (summy > sum){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "longest segment"? Is it a contiguous sub-sequence from the sequence of numbers? How is `l,r` addressed? `l` is `left`? I thought `l` was output, but then it's a parameter? It seems like you could do it in at most `O(n)`, but I'm not quite sure what it is.

Comment: Input dataset is length of array (N), number of tests (K), elements of array, tests (l(left border of array) and S(sum)). Output are k anwsers - longest part of array from left to right less than S (anwser is right border)

Comment: So in your second test, `N = (1, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 5, 3)`, indexed from 0, inclusive `left = 0`, `sum = 5`, and the is exclusive `right = 3`, because the right-bound of <= is `1 + 4 + 0` and when you add 5, it goes over, so that's the answer? Seems straightforward.

Comment: Maybe we could help you more If you edit your question with the "too slow" code you have now? You could pre-calculate the sums from [0..i] (energy, [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)) in `O(n)`, then you could use the [upper bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) `O(log n)`? I don't think it makes much difference for 7 queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your teacher meant, was, instead of storing `arr[i] = input_i`:

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    fscanf(f,"%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

you could store the running sum, `arr[i] = \sum_{n=0}^{i} input_n`. This is discrete version of taking the integral.

```
int energy = 0; /* Or whatever. */
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int value;
    if(fscanf(f,"%d",&value) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    energy += value;
    arr[i] = energy;
}
```

You might have to switch to `unsigned int` if you have a lot of values, because it is a ring, whereas `int` has undefined characteristics if it goes over `INT_MAX`, (but probably works.) Because the problem is linear, this allows you to look at only the endpoints, `arr[r] - arr[l]`. Thus, you can reduce incrementing at every step, `O(n)`, and use a binary search, `O(log n)`. Specifically, you will need to take the upper bound. Like [bsearch](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-166/stdlib.subproj/bsearch.c.auto.html), but in `C++`, [std::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound).

Comment: I'm sure you have nailed the intention of the instructor's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For speed; if you know the sum of the segment (l, r), then you can determine the sum of the segment (l+1, r+1) by subtracting the entry at array[l] and adding the entry at array[r+1].

Therefore (untested):

```
void FindHighestSum (const uint32_t *array, uint32_t arraySize, uint32_t segmentSize) {
    uint32_t bestSumPos;
    uint64_t bestSum;
    uint32_t r;
    uint32_t l;
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    if(arraySize < segmentSize) {
        printf("Error: Array too small for segment size\n");
        return;
    }

    // Find sum of first segment

    for(r = 0; r < segmentSize; r++) {
        sum += array[r];
    }

    // Sum of first segment is the largest sum so far

    bestSumPos = 0;
    bestSum = sum;

    // Find largest sum of all segments

    for(l = 1; l < arraySize - segmentSize; l++) {
        sum = sum - array[l] + array[r];
        r++;

        if(sum > bestSum) {
            // Found a new largest sum
            bestSumPos = l;
            bestSum = sum;
        }
    }
    printf("Highest sum from %" PRIu32 " to %" PRIu32 " (sum is %" PRIu64 ")\n", bestSumPos, bestSumPos + segmentSize - 1, bestSum);
}
```